# How can I plot two concentric circles with a polygon inscribed in one and circumscribed about the other

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry

So I am new to Mathematica still learning basic codes.. However I need help to become quicker in my research. Can anyone help me with the simplicit code to plot 2 concentric circles and a polygon of sides n (that I can manipulate) inscribed in one circle and circumscribed about the other.

Comment: can you post a sample image - a drawing or from a website.

Comment: Are your polygons always regular (as kirma assumes in his answer)? Not all polygons are circumscribable or inscribable.

Comment: So the polygon does not have to always be regular, as long as I have the circumscribed and inscribed, and my circles fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler and minimal version

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Cos[Pi/n]], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
 Green, Line[{Cos[2 Pi #/n], Sin[2 Pi #/n]} & /@ Range[0, n]]}],
 {n, 3, 30, 1}]
```

[image]

Inner circle will adjust itself according to the polygon.

**For fixed inner circle**

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 1/Cos[Pi/n]], 
 Green, Line[
 1/Cos[Pi/n] {Cos[2 Pi #/n], Sin[2 Pi #/n]} & /@ Range[0, n]]}, 
 PlotRange -> 2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {n, 3, 30, 1}]
```

If you don't use `PlotRange`, you would not be able to see the difference.

Comment: Alternatively: `Manipulate[Graphics[{Blue, Circle[], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Cos[π/n]], Directive[EdgeForm[Green], FaceForm[]], RegularPolygon[n]}], {n, 3, 30, 1}]`

Comment: I am still with M9, @J.M.

Comment: That's fine, I left it just for people who can try it out on later versions.

Comment: If I want the polygon to stay circumscribed about the circle however with the circle inside to stay fixed,, so as n increases the circle inside is fixed but the polygon is still circumscribed about it.

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: hi @Sarah. sorry for the delay. I made an edit. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Sumit Thank you for answering and your efforts, however in this way the 2nd circle Is no longer fixed, I want both circles to be fixed. And to be able to control the polygon that stays circumscribed and inscribed as it should be.

Comment: With concentric circles, you can make only regular polygon, and that will be possible when the circles are at particular ratio. A slightest deviation can drastically increase the order of polygon (`n` can be `>20` or `>50`). Only further change I can suggest is a way to rotate the polygon in my code. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: How about if I do not care about it being a regular polygon all the time, so the thing is circumscribed trajectories, similar to a billiard table @Sumit ...So it is random for the lines but my circles to stay fixed

Comment: If you have concentric circles, you don't have any other choice. If you want to use random polygon, then you would not be able to keep the circles concentric. Take a look at the [images of this site](http://magoosh.com/gmat/2012/inscribed-and-circumscribed-circles-and-polygons-on-the-gmat/) and you can understand. In that case what you can try is to fix  the polygon and one circle and find the other circle.

Answer (score 6):

There are numerous ways to do this in Mathematica, and it's hard to say which would be most useful for learning. Here's one; a unit circle is drawn, then a polygon with no filling and black edge on basis of `CirclePoints` which generates points of a regular polygon lying on the unit circle. Finally, mean of two first points is taken, and distance to the origin is used as the radius of the incircle. `Manipulate` is then used to control the value of `n`.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{points = CirclePoints[n]}, 
  Graphics[{Circle[], FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[points], 
    Circle[{0, 0}, Norm[Mean[Take[points, 2]]]]}]], {n, 3, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a one-line derivation of the formula for the inradius of a regular $n$-gon, based on kirma's observation: `PowerExpand[Simplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[(1 + E^(2 π I/n))/2]]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. It was a strange experiment of the "avoid explicit trigonometry" sorts. :)

Comment: Why all the anathema? ;) :P

Comment: @J.M. I guess I wanted to write the solution starting from `CirclePoints`, and it didn't turn out too awkward to do so. The first sentence in my answer expresses the Weltschmerz involved in expressing the solution only in this manner. :)