# How Can I plot two concentric circles with a polygon inscribed in one and circumscribed about the other however I want the polygon to manipulated

Tags: graphics, geometry, polygons

So this code is to plot two concentric circles with a polygon inscribed in one and circumscribed about the other:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Cos[Pi/n]], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
 Green, Line[{Cos[2 Pi #/n], Sin[2 Pi #/n]} & /@ Range[0, n]]}],
 {n, 3, 30, 1}]
```

What can I do to make three additional changes : control the polygon inside in a way that it can be closed or simply lines that end, not necessarily periodic .

To make myself more clear I would want to deal with it like a billiard ball that might make a closed trajectory or a trajectory that ends
Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by making the polygon unclosed, and not necessarily periodic. Could you explain further?

Comment: "polygon unclosed" - that ain't a polygon anymore, innit?

Comment: you are right I was not clear enough,, what I mean is that I can control those lines inside in a way it can stay a polygon or become lines. More like a billiard table where the ball might make a closed trajectory or it might hit a corner and end, did you get my point?

Comment: I edited my question, hope its clearer

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, Cos[Pi/n]], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
   Green, Line[{Cos[2 Pi #/n], Sin[2 Pi #/n]} & /@ 
     Range[0, 2 n]]}], {n, 3, 30, .2}]
```

Comment: Looking more in its details , Actually this is perfect! Thank you

Comment: Quick question what does .2 in the (n,3,30,.2) stand for. Sorry I am new to mathematica so do not know if it means something specific. And how come when I changed it to 2 the whole thing changed.

Comment: `2Pi/n` is angle at each corner. For regular polygon it is an integer when you write the vertices in parametric form (inside `Line[]`). Your [earlier question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113467/how-can-i-plot-two-concentric-circles-with-a-polygon-inscribed-in-one-and-circum/113473#113473) was about regular polygon, so I used integral steps for `n`. It's not `Mathematica`, rather `Mathematics` :)

Comment: thank you . I thought ".2 " was a symbole in mathematica for smth (thought its a mathematica thing) . So from your answer I get its "0.2"? No my question is Just a symbol question not a mathematics one. thanks anyways

Comment: Sorry but this does not keep the polygon circumscribed about the circle inside, as we increase n the polygon is not longer tangent to the circle?